# Deleting a head node in the kernel list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a kernel list is added already, I am just looking for a way of removal the HEAD Node.

My snippet of code:

```
struct kool_list {
     int data;
     struct list_head list;
 };

struct kool_list_senders {
     struct kool_list tx;
};

struct kool_list_senders hlist[10];

struct kool_list *entry = NULL;
struct list_head *curr, *next;

curr  =  hlist[2]->tx.list; // Example one hash index addition in linked list 
next = curr->next;
entry =  list_entry(curr, struct kool_list, list);
list_del(entry);
if (unlikely(NULL != entry)) {
    kfree(entry);
    entry = NULL;
}
curr = next;
```

I know the removal of head node in linked list, But I am looking for kernel list fasion removal of head node.

Comment: if the head node you refer to is first entry in the list you can use `list_first_entry()` to get the entry and `list_del()` to delete it just like any other node in the list.

Comment: One thing to note in a linux kernel linked list is that the HEAD node is a sentinel node which doesn't contain actual data. So, when you mean "delete the HEAD node" it is assumed you are trying to delete the first node pointed to by the HEAD node.  https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LinkedLists . To delete the first node in your list pointed to by the HEAD node, you can use the api mentioned by @luke

Comment: Thanks Luke and Pradeepmcp... Okay i will use the first entry list_first_entry() to get the entry but after deleting, how should i take care the next of the node as the head node, Can i use the same fashion I am trying to do as explained above code snippet?